# Error while using the Slider from React-Slick in SPFX webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I am trying to use react slick Slider in my SPFx web part as below.

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default function SimpleSlider() {
  var settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  };
  return (
    <Slider {...settings}>
      <div>
        <h3>1</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>2</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>3</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>4</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>5</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>6</h3>
      </div>
    </Slider>
  );
}
```

During compilation I am getting error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Settings | Readonly<Settings>): Slider', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; dots: boolean; infinite: boolean; speed: number; slidesToShow: number; slidesToScroll: number; lazyLoad: string; autoplaySpeed: number; initialSlide: number; arrows: boolean; draggable: boolean; adaptiveHeight: boolean; useCSS: boolean; useTransform: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Settings>'.
      Types of property 'lazyLoad' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'LazyLoadTypes'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Settings, context: any): Slider', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; dots: boolean; infinite: boolean; speed: number; slidesToShow: number; slidesToScroll: number; lazyLoad: string; autoplaySpeed: number; initialSlide: number; arrows: boolean; draggable: boolean; adaptiveHeight: boolean; useCSS: boolean; useTransform: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Settings>'.
      Types of property 'lazyLoad' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'LazyLoadTypes'.ts(2769)
No quick fixes available
```

Kindly, help me on this.

Comment: What value you passed for `lazyLoad` proeprty? Which version of `react-slick` are you using?

Comment: react-slick verion:0.29.0

Comment: I did not pass anything to the lazy Load property. This is the only single file and did not ran even due to compile time error.

Comment: what version of SPFx you are using ?

Comment: @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.15.2